# org.uncommons.reportng.ReportNGException: Failed generating HTML report

Tags: testng, reportng

```
    [TestNG] Reporter org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter@1add4d8 failed
   [testng] org.uncommons.reportng.ReportNGException: Failed generating HTML report.
   [testng]     at org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter.generateReport(HTMLReporter.java:103)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1032)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:991)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1282)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1246)
   [testng] Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'sortByTestClass' in  class org.uncommons.reportng.ReportNGUtils threw exception class java.lang.NullPointerException : null
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:246)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:175)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:327)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTExpression.value(ASTExpression.java:51)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTSetDirective.render(ASTSetDirective.java:95)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:55)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIfStatement.render(ASTIfStatement.java:70)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:230)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:256)
   [testng]     at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.mergeTemplate(Velocity.java:449)
   [testng]     at org.uncommons.reportng.AbstractReporter.generateFile(AbstractReporter.java:94)
   [testng]     at org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter.createResults(HTMLReporter.java:163)
   [testng]     at org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter.generateReport(HTMLReporter.java:97)
   [testng]     ... 4 more
```

Hi All, 
Has anyone faced to this exception? It is being thrown during report generation and I cannot identify the cause.
Thanks for help

Comment: I will appreciate any kind of advice/suggestion

Comment: http://reportunit.relevantcodes.com/